# Get point of Interest nearby

Tags: windows-phone-8, here-api

Windows Phone 8 has offline Maps with Point of Interests. Can I access the point of interest database from the device? I want to show a list of sights near-by.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the new [HERE Maps Launchers](http://developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!maps-and-navigation/here-launchers.html) may solve your problem, specifically the `ExploremapsExplorePlacesTask` class. The use case is described in the [documentation](http://developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!maps-and-navigation/here-launchers/here-launchers-api-reference.html;#toc_ExploremapsExplorePlacesTask) as:

> The `ExploremapsExplorePlacesTask` allows you to start the Maps
>   application where the nearby places of interest are shown.

The associated [demo](http://developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!maps-and-navigation/here-launchers/here-launchers-api-demo.html;#toc_Exploreplaces) displays the map as shown:

[image]

Furthermore, there is an upcoming [webinar](http://developer.nokia.com/Resources/Multimedia/Webinars.xhtml) on this subject early next month.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Launchers are not what I am looking for. My intention is to query the POI and display them in my custom list.

Comment: For a **web-based** solution, you could use the [Places REST API](http://developer.here.com/places) to make a query to obtain points of interest nearby - just do a [discover/here](http://developer.here.com/apiexplorer/examples/api-for-rest/places-search/explore-nearby-places.html) request. This headless API would give you the flexibility to display the data as you see fit. Using the launchers `PlacesShowDetailsByIdHrefTask` in WP8 still makes sense though should you need to drill down in more detail, since they would access the **on-board** data rather than requiring an internet connection.